# Time span or Duration formatting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time

I have 1 question regarding the time span/duration management.

Currently, I have a record in the database representing a time in `mmss` format. Example: 5030 that suppose to mean 50 minutes and 30 seconds.

And I wanted to display this at my web page in this format:

- Example: 4020 to 40m 20s.
- Example: 6012 to 1h 12s.
- Example: 6515 to 1h 4m 15s.

Is there any way that I could achieve this? The data stored inside the DB is in string format. I am currently using VB.NET language in an ASP.NET application.

I searched all over the internet but I keep on getting results for representing time, rather than a duration.

Currently, I am doing it in this way, but I am still unable to get the hour to be displayed:

```
If arrayValueInside.Length > 0 Then
    If arrayValueInside(0) = "STOPPING TIME" Then
        Dim strTime As String = arrayValueInside(1).Trim()
        Select Case strTime.Length
            Case 1
                strTime = strTime & "s"
            Case 2
                strTime = strTime & "s"
            Case 3
                strTime = strTime.Substring(0, 1) & "m " & strTime.Substring(1, 2) & "s"
            Case 4
                strTime = strTime.Substring(0, 2) & "m " & strTime.Substring(2, 2) & "s"
            '   If Integer.Parse(strTime) >= 6000 Then
            '       Return strTime.Substring(0, 2) + "m" + strTime.Substring(1, 2) + "s"
            '   Else
            '   End If
            Case 5
                strTime = strTime.Substring(0, 3) & "m " & strTime.Substring(3, 2) & "s"
        End Select
```

Please let me know if there is anything not clear in the information I provided.

Comment: Do you now how to parse a string to an integer?  If you had an integer variable with the value of 5030, can you work out how to manipulate that value to determine how many hours and minutes it represents?  Once you figure that out, formatting back to a string a trival.

Comment: Is the string always in the format mmss? If so you should be able to chop into mm and ss and pass the values to the System.TimesSpan() which has a bunch of overloads

Comment: Will minutes ever be greater than 99?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway it is possible..since it record the total idling time for a machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the time format is presented in the form `mmss`, I think it should also be considered that the minutes value, in some cases, might exceed `"99"` and could be expressed by 3 (or maybe more) numbers.

The [TimeSpan structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.TimeSpan);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) has an internal mechanism to calculate the units of time which can be useful here. All the units are transposed and measured in Days. If one unit has a value that exceeds it's maximum, it will be recalculated in the next unit.
 So, 70 minutes will become 1 hour and 10 minutes.

Here, the 2 rightmost characters are considered to represents the seconds value; all the other (2 or more) represent minutes.

```
Dim input As String = "12845"
Dim seconds As Integer = Integer.Parse(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 2))
Dim minutes As Integer = Integer.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 2))
Dim ts As New TimeSpan(0, 0, minutes, seconds)

Dim TimeFormat = $"{ts.Hours}h {ts.Minutes}m {ts.Seconds}s"
```

The TimeFormat string will be `2h 8m 45s`.

If [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) is not available, use the [String.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) method:

```
Dim TimeFormat = String.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)
```

A slightly modified method, which doesn't return a unit measure if that unit value is 0.
If the input string is `"12045"`, the previous method would return `2h 0m 45s`. This one will return `2h 45s`.

```
Dim TimeFormat As String() = New String() {
    (If(ts.Hours > 0, ts.Hours & "h", "")),
    (If(ts.Minutes > 0, " " & ts.Minutes & "m", "")),
    (If(ts.Seconds > 0, " " & ts.Seconds & "s", ""))
}

Dim output As String = $"{TimeFormat(0)}{TimeFormat(1)}{TimeFormat(2)}"
```

Comment: Just a note... `Dim seconds As Integer = Integer.Parse(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 2))` The second parameter is not necessary since substring will go to the end of the string but your presentation is probably better for consistency with the next line. :-)

Comment: @Mary  Of course. Sometimes, in examples, I prefer the explicit form, in the hope of providing a better *view* of what's happening. But the OP can make good use of your note. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This is the solution i am searching for..Thank you so much :D ..Marked as answer !